# How to slide down menu

Tags: jquery

i'm new to jquery and i'm having some trouble solving everything i need to do. I've created a fixed menu with submenu that slides down on Click, but i would also like for it to slide down when scrolling to a certain div, i first made something like this

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop()>590)
 {
      $('#menu').slideDown(800);
 }
 else
 {
     $('#menu').slideUp(800);
 }
});
```

but i would prefer to trigger it based on passing trought a certain div and not on height. Can someone help me please? thanks a lot!!

Comment: could you check scrollTop against the div top?

Comment: Have you tried $(yourdiv).mouseover event?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the offset of said certain div:

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > $("#certain-div").offset().top) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the current position of every defined tag. 
Check herefor "[jQuery Offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)"